# How to extend bootcamp partition?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, partition

When I was installing windows 7 on my mac I allocated 55GB to my bootcamp partition, I now realise that it is not enough for me. is there a way to extend it, without loosing any data and re-instaling windows?

Additionally, is it possible to store files on Macintosh HD partition (as it shows up when I access my computer from windows) while using windows?
That would solve the problem, however I'm not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

*Late note:* iPartition cannot handle CoreStorage or APFS volumes & is no longer supported by its author. [Coriolis](https://coriolis-systems.com) is now a single page site, with unsupported free license downloads for some of its old software.
If you are still on a pre-CoreStorage macOS, then it is still very much the tool to use.

---

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend [**iPartition**](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php).

iPartition allows you to modify Boot Camp partitions just like regular partitions. iPartition will reconfigure the Windows partitions automatically.

> You can use iPartition on drives that contain Boot Camp volumes; in fact, you can even resize your Windows partitions, and let iPartition take care of reconfiguring the Windows boot process for you.
>
> [image: iPartition Screenshot 1]
>
> [image: iPartition Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1) First, shrink an **adjacent** partition to make room using Disk Utility in MacOS:

- Launch Disk Utility in MacOS
- Identify the Windows partition and the adjacent ones
- Using Disk Utility, shrink one (or both) adjacent partitions

2) Then in Windows, expand the bootcamp partition.

Comment: what do you mean buy that? Should I make another partition like 15GB and than merge it with bootcamp one? I don't understand.

Comment: Breakdown of step 1:

a) Launch Disk Utility in MacOS
b) Identify the Windows partition and the adjacent ones.
c) Using Disk Utility, shrink one (or both) adjacent partitions.

Comment: There is no direct support for resizing the Boot Camp Windows volume from inside either macOS or Windows. You need 3rd party software to do this safely.

Comment: If so, that's partly because Disk Utility was rewritten a few years, and it lost a number of valuable capabilities. (I guess someone decided the old code base was hard to maintain/extend when they started working on APFS.)

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation for iPartition, I've been using Coriolis Software's iPartition & iDefrag for many years - seemingly bullet proof, and will allow you to shorten the Mac-HD partition & lengthen the Windows partition in one operation.

Alternatively (or as well), for Windows to be able to see (have r/w access) to a HFS+ partition, you need a HFS+ file system driver installed in Windows.  I think there's free ones, but I have used & can recommend Paragon Software's pair of file-sys drivers, for Windows to access HFS+ partitions, and for Mac to have r/w access to NTFS partitions (by itself Mac can only read NTFS, not write).

Comment: AFAIK the Boot Camp WindowsSupport drivers allow Windows to read/write to HFS+ without the need for 3rd party software…

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for resizing the Boot Camp Windows volume from inside either macOS or Windows. You need 3rd party software to do this safely.

The current Apps that can do this are [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/), Paragon
[CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/) or Twocanoes' [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/)

Never attempt to resize any other way - you will break something.

Comment: Partition Magic will break something? CoI?